Add back in a pre-existing partition at a known location on disk into a replaced partition table (merging partition tables, if you will)
Because I was in a hurry, I copied a disk image of under 80GB onto a 1TB disk with a new GPT header and new partitions to get a system working again. However, after the 90GB mark lies a previous partition that I never overwrote, at least not consciously. Before replacing the partition table, I wrote down the fdisk output of where the old partition was.
How would I add back in such a "lost" partition with fdisk, assuming it wasn't overwritten yet? I assume there is a good chance that I may have by accident have overwritten parts of it after all, but in case I haven't, it would save me some time to just add it back in as-is.
Here is the fdisk output as it was before writing the lost partition (the 2nd one listed):
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1 --bytes
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: CT1000P3PSSD8                           
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E3C4F845-4E6F-4AB1-9B84-F7A92E16715F

Device             Start        End    Sectors         Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     206847     204800    104857600 EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 188950528 1953525134 1764574607 903462198784 Linux filesystem

(I assume this question is already answered somewhere on the internet, but I failed to make a search engine spit out anything relevant. Sorry if this is a duplicate!)

What is the output of fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1 now?

Use the same "New partition" command in fdisk, only be careful to answer No to its prompt about erasing a detected filesystem header.

It worked, thanks! It said Partition #4 contains a crypto_LUKS signature. and I answered no to keep it, and mounting the partition afterward went just fine. Everything looks in order.
